# Key Interpolation Javascript

Tags: javascript

I was reading key interpolation in javascript and the article, it says following is a key interpolation

```
const example = {key1: value1, key2: value2}
```

and to add new value to the above object we will do the following

```
const example1 = {...example, [key3]:value3}
```

and this gives o/p as:

```
{key1: value1, key2: value2,key3: value3}
```

The article says bracket is required for key interpolation.

I tried the same things as

```
const example1 = {...example, key3:value3}
```

and it gives the same result. 
Is there any difference between them or they are the same as they give the same o/p?

Comment: If you're quoting the article correctly, I suggest finding a different article. From the quotes above, the one you're reading is at least confusing, and possibly actually wrong.

Comment: It is called [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), not interpolation, and it has nothing to do with the square brackets. The square brackets are needed in any context to defined the object keys that contain spaces and other characters (`:` f.e.) that have a special meaning and when the key value is computed at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it says following is a key interpolation `const example = {key1: value1, key2: value2}`

I don't see any "key interpolation" there.

> ...and to add new value to the above object we will do the following const `example1 = {...example, [key3]:value3}` and this gives o/p as `{key1: value1, key2: value2,key3: value3}`.

Only if you have a variable called `key3` which has the value `"key3"` in it, which seems like a really confusing example for an article to have.

> The article says bracket is required for key interpolation.
>
> I tried the same things as `const example1 = {...example, key3:value3}` and it gives the same result. Is there any difference between them or they are the same as they give the same o/p?

The difference is whether you're providing the name of the property (the key) using literal notation (no `[]`) or computed notation (with `[]`):

```js
// Literal notation, adds a property called `key` to the object
const obj1 = {key: "value"};
console.log(obj1.key); // "value"

// Computed notation, adds a property whose name comes from the
// contents of the variable `key` to the object:
const key = "propertyName";
const obj2 = {[key]: "value"};
console.log(obj2.key);          // undefined, there isn't any property with the name "key"
console.log(obj2.propertyName); // "value"
console.log(obj2[key]);         // "value"
```

Comment: FWIW, I get into computed property (and method) notation in Chapter 5 of my new book out in a couple of months, see my profile for details if you're interested.

Comment: ohh okay got it. I actually confused about the bracket part. Thank you

Comment: @Manish - That's easy to do! :-) Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

They are not the same.

If you use string literals, then they behave the same.

These are identical:

```js
const example1 = {foo: 'bar'}
const example2 = {'foo': 'bar'}
const example3 = {['foo']: 'bar'}
```

The difference appears when you try to put an expression in a key:

```js
const keyName = 'foo'

const example1 = {keyName: 'bar'}   //{keyName: 'bar'}
const example2 = {[keyName]: 'bar'} //{foo: 'bar'}
```

The interpolator syntax (`[]`) allows you to put any expression into the key, for example, this is also valid:

```js
const fn = foo => foo.length

const example = {
  [10 - fn('baz') + 'baz']: 'bar'
}

//{7baz: 'bar'}
```

Comment: Thank you. Got the concept. The last point explains the real need for brackets. Great.